# Excel conditional Formatting per row

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

What I am trying to achieve is a conditional formatting of rows in a table looking for changes based on a backup of an older table.

If there were any change to the table and it doesn't match the backup, then the row where the change was performed will change it's style.

What I managed to do is to add a formula:

```
=IF(OR(B2<>'1LinkBU'!B2,C2<>'1LinkBU'!C2,D2<>'1LinkBU'!D2),1,0)
```

Checking if the rows are not equal to their counterparts on the backup table. If anything was changed in this row the formula cell gets a value of 1. And then in the conditional formatting I selected the second row and in the formula I said that if `E2 = 1` then the formatting is valid.

The thing is, this table supposed to grow a lot and be used by users who doesn't know how to use formulas as well as it really isn't convenient to enter a specific conditional formatting for each raw.

Also, in the linked file I uploaded I recorded a macro that creates the row style I want but I don't know how to create a code that will use it.

Is it possible to go through row2 down to what ever will be the last row and for each "1" value in the E column apply the Row style to the whole row?

Comment: OK apparently I was just over thinking this! It was actually very simple to do...
all I had to do is change the formula from =$E$2=1 into =($E2=1) and apply the conditional formatting to the whole range of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK apparently I was just over thinking this! It was actually very simple to do... all I had to do is change the formula from =$E$2=1 into =($E2=1) and apply the conditional formatting to the whole range of the table.